# iReport: How to make a group depend on another

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm using `iReport 3.7.1` and I'd to know how to make one group depend on another group. I'd like the second to appear only when the first one changes.

**Example**: Let's consider an example of three levels, we have a `group A` that includes the `group B`, and `group B` includes `group C`.

In the PDF, `group A` appears before `group B` and `group B` appears before `group C`. On each page we should have:

```
A1 B11 c11 c12
A1 B12 C13
A2 B21 C21
A2 B22 C21 C22 C23 ...
```

Every time the the value of B changes, the value of A should appear before.

Answer (score 0):

In iReport, right-click on the name of your report in the report inspector and click "Add Report Group" to launch the New Group Wizard. Add A, B, and C as groups. Add header bands for each group. Put a textbox in each group header band to define the group, and click the "Print Repeated Values" checkbox to show the group header each time the subgroup changes.