# JasperReports, iReport 3.7: group dependency

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

How could I write Group Expressions in *iReport 3.7.1* with groups and sub groups dependencies?

My report output should be as below:

```
A1
B1
C1
Person 1
Person 2

A2
B2
C3
Person 3

A2
B3
C4
Person 4

C4
Person 5
```

NB : C is sub group of B and B is a sub group of A.
B appears only when it has a new value (person 4 and person 5 have the same value B3 => B3 appears only the first time and we that person 5 has B3). I just want the group A to appear every time the group B changes, just like the case of Person 3 and Person 4, we have the same group A (A2) but B has changed from B2 to B3 => A2 should appear even if it still has the same value.

How can i make this dependency?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iReport: How to make a group depend on another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555606/ireport-how-to-make-a-group-depend-on-another)

Comment: Hi Alex, the post "iReport: How to make a group depend on another" seems to treate the same problem, but there is no anwser.

Comment: This is your question too. This is wrong practice to post the same question again and again. You can improve your old question and you can also start bounty. See also [How to start a bounty on question with outdated answers but having low reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120685/how-to-start-a-bounty-on-question-with-outdated-answers-but-having-low-reputatio) and [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: By the way, your question is still unclear for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iReport, right-click on your report's name in the Report Inspector. Click "Add Report Group". In the Group Criteria area, under "Group by the following report object", choose a field to group on. This will be your "A" field. Repeat this for "B" and "C". In your detail band, place a text field for "Person".

Make sure that the ORDER BY clause in your query orders by A, B, C.